# Checking ID against Access Table and looping through an SQL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I posted a [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330408/selecting-an-item-in-a-gridview-and-adding-to-the-list/4332989#4332989) for Selecting an item in a gridview and then adding it to the list, which I found a solution for, it takes the value of the gridview, in this case an ID number and then outputs them on another page in a gridview.

My question is, is it possible to check the value of the ID against a table in an access database to then display more information about the product?

I have the following code on my Basket page:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["CartSess"] != null)
        {
            List<BasketClass> cart = (List<BasketClass>)Session["CartSess"];

            foreach (BasketClass BookID in (List<BasketClass>)Session["CartSess"])
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = cart;

                GridView1.DataBind();
                AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [BookID], [book_title] FROM [tblBook] WHERE [BookID]=" + BookID;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, it only returns one value based upon the last one that the user has chosen, is there a way to loop through each of them so it will keep adding to the new gridview that I have placed on the page which is bound to AccessDataSource1?

Comment: I didnt understand it well, I delete my answer to see it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
string items = "";
string sql = "SELECT [BookID], [book_title] FROM [tblBook] WHERE [BookID] in (";
foreach (BasketClass BookID in (List<BasketClass>)Session["CartSess"])
{
    items += BookID & ",";
}
//Remove the trailing ","
items.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
GridView1.DataSource = cart;
GridView1.DataBind();
AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql & items & ")";
```